# Handling auth with React Hooks

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, react-hooks

I've been chasing my tail for hours now trying to figure out how to handle auth on my component using firebase and react hooks.

I've created a custom `useAuth` hook that is *intended* to handle all the auth behaviors. My thought was to put a `useEffect` on the root of my component tree that would trigger if the `firebase.auth.onAuthStateChanged()` ever changed (ie, user is now logged out / logged in.) But, at this point after making a million unsuccessful changes I really don't know what I'm doing anymore.

Here is the code that I have...

**RootPage component**

```
const RootPage = ({ Component, pageProps }): JSX.Element => {
  const { logoutUser, authStatus } = useAuth();
  const router = useRouter();

  useEffect(() => {
    authStatus();
  }, [authStatus]);

  ...
}
```

my thought was ok, lets trigger `authStatus` on mount, but that ends up with me lying about my dependencies. So, in an effort to not lie about my deps, I added `authStatus` to the deps. Logging out and then logging in results in this:

[image]

**useAuth hook**

```
const useAuth = () => {
  const { fetchUser, resetUser, userData } = useUser();
  const { currentUser } = firebaseAuth;

  const registerUser = async (username, email, password) => {
    try {
      const credentials = await firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
        email,
        password
      );
      const { uid } = credentials.user;
      await firebaseFirestore
        .collection('users')
        .doc(credentials.user.uid)
        .set({
          username,
          points: 0,
          words: 0,
          followers: 0,
          following: 0,
          created: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
        });
      fetchUser(uid);
      console.log('user registered', credentials);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };

  const loginUser = async (email, password) => {
    try {
      // login to firebase
      await firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
      // take the current users id
      const { uid } = firebaseAuth.currentUser;
      // update the user in redux
      fetchUser(uid);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };

  const logoutUser = async () => {
    try {
      // logout from firebase
      await firebaseAuth.signOut();
      // reset user state in redux
      resetUser();
      return;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };

  const authStatus = () => {
    firebaseAuth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (user) {
        console.log('User logged in.');
        // On page refresh, if user persists (but redux state is lost), update user in redux
        if (userData === initialUserState) {
          console.log('triggered');
          // update user in redux store with data from user collection
          fetchUser(user.uid);
        }
        return;
      }
      console.log('User logged out.');
    });
  };

  return { currentUser, registerUser, loginUser, logoutUser, authStatus };
};

export default useAuth;
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm relatively certain that react hooks are only meant for reusable pieces of logic, so if the purpose of your hook is to contact firebase in every single component you're using it, along with rerendering and refreshing state every time that component is updated, then it's fine, but you can't use hooks for storing global auth state, which is how auth should be stored.

You're looking for react context instead.

```
import React, {createContext, useContext, useState, useEffect, ReactNode} from 'react'

const getJwt = () => localStorage.getItem('jwt') || ''

const setJwt = (jwt: string) => localStorage.setItem('jwt', jwt)

const getUser = () => JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user') || 'null')

const setUser = (user: object) => localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user))

const logout = () => localStorage.clear()

const AuthContext = createContext({
  jwt: '',
  setJwt: setJwt,
  user: {},
  setUser: setUser,
  loading: false,
  setLoading: (loading: boolean) => {},
  authenticate: (jwt: string, user: object) => {},
  logout: () => {},
})

export const useAuth = () => useContext(AuthContext)

const Auth = ({children}: {children: ReactNode}) => {
  const auth = useAuth()

  const [jwt, updateJwt] = useState(auth.jwt)
  const [user, updateUser] = useState(auth.user)
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)

  useEffect(() => {
    updateJwt(getJwt())
    updateUser(getUser())
  }, [])

  const value = {
    jwt: jwt,
    setJwt: (jwt: string) => {
      setJwt(jwt)
      updateJwt(jwt)
    },
    user: user,
    setUser: (user: object) => {
      setUser(user)
      updateUser(user)
    },
    loading: loading,
    setLoading: setLoading,
    authenticate: (jwt: string, user: object) => {
      setJwt(jwt)
      updateJwt(jwt)
      setUser(user)
      updateUser(user)
    },
    logout: () => {
      localStorage.removeItem('jwt')
      localStorage.removeItem('user')
      updateJwt('')
      updateUser({})
      setLoading(false)
    },
  }

  return <AuthContext.Provider value={value}>
    {children}
  </AuthContext.Provider>
}

export default Auth

...

// app.tsx

import Auth from './auth'

...

<Auth>
  <Router/>
</Auth>

// or something like that

...

import {useAuth} from './auth'

// in any component to pull auth from global context state
```

You can change that according to whatever you need.

Answer (score 0):

I know the issue why its happening but don't know the solution...But i am not fully sure...Look how react works is if any parents re render it also cause re render the children..ok?Its mean if any reason your apps is re rendering and the useAuth keep firing...so for this there to much console log.But i am not sure that it will work or not..give me your repo i will try on my local computer

```js
const RootPage = ({ Component, pageProps }): JSX.Element => {
  const { logoutUser, authStatus,currentUser } = useAuth();
  const router = useRouter();

  useEffect(() => {
    authStatus();
  }, [currentUser]);
  
  //only fire when currentUser change

  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your useEffect hook like so:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const unsub = firebaseAuth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (user) {
        console.log('User logged in.');
        // On page refresh, if user persists (but redux state is lost), update user in redux
        if (userData === initialUserState) {
          console.log('triggered');
          // update user in redux store with data from user collection
          fetchUser(user.uid);
        }
      } else {
        console.log('User logged out.');
      }
    });
  return ()=> unsub;
},[])
```